# Setting Series as index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm using python 2.7 to take a numerical column of my dataframe `data` and make it an individual object (series) with an index of dates that is another column from `data`.

```
new_series = pd.Series(data['numerical_column'] , index=data['dates'])
```

However, when I do this, I get a bunch of `NaN` values in the Series:

```
dates
1980-01-31   NaN
1980-02-29   NaN
1980-03-31   NaN
1980-04-30   NaN
1980-05-31   NaN
1980-06-30   NaN
...
```

Why does my `numerical_data` values just disappear?

I realize that I can apparently achieve this goal by doing the following, although I'm curious why my initial approach failed.

```
new_series = data.set_index('dates')['numerical_column']
```

Comment: jezrael gave the perfect answer of how to solve the problem.  but just to make sure you understood why your attempt failed... if you pass a pandas object as the data parameter, along with an index parameter, pandas attempts to reindex the data parameter with the index parameter. `pd.Series(data['numerical_column'], data['dates'])` is equivalent to `data['numerical_column'].reindex(data['dates'])`  When stated this way, it's more obvious why your values disappeared.  `data['numerical_column']` has no values for the indices specified in `data['dates']`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is problem with not align index of column `data['numerical_column']`.

So need convert it to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
new_series = pd.Series(data['numerical_column'].values , index=data['dates'])
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = pd.DataFrame({
'dates': {0: datetime.date(1980, 1, 31), 1: datetime.date(1980, 2, 29), 
          2: datetime.date(1980, 3, 31), 3: datetime.date(1980, 4, 30), 
          4: datetime.date(1980, 5, 31), 5: datetime.date(1980, 6, 30)}, 
'numerical_column': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 0}})
print (data)
        dates  numerical_column
0  1980-01-31                 1
1  1980-02-29                 4
2  1980-03-31                 5
3  1980-04-30                 3
4  1980-05-31                 1
5  1980-06-30                 0

new_series = pd.Series(data['numerical_column'].values , index=data['dates'])
print (new_series)
dates
1980-01-31    1
1980-02-29    4
1980-03-31    5
1980-04-30    3
1980-05-31    1
1980-06-30    0
dtype: int64
```

But method with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) is nicer, but slowier:

```
#[60000 rows x 2 columns]
data = pd.concat([data]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [65]: %timeit pd.Series(data['numerical_column'].values , index=data['dates'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 308 µs per loop

In [66]: %timeit data.set_index('dates')['numerical_column']
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 ms per loop
```

**Verification**:

If index of column has same index, it works nice:

```
s = data.set_index('dates')['numerical_column']
df = s.to_frame()
print (df)
            numerical_column
dates                       
1980-01-31                 1
1980-02-29                 4
1980-03-31                 5
1980-04-30                 3
1980-05-31                 1
1980-06-30                 0

new_series = pd.Series(df['numerical_column'] , index=data['dates'])
print (new_series)
dates
1980-01-31    1
1980-02-29    4
1980-03-31    5
1980-04-30    3
1980-05-31    1
1980-06-30    0
Name: numerical_column, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank god I came across this answer: I have spent hours trying to figure it out. Ridiculous though that one must manually `.values`; Python, why do you first give and then take from us? :p